# Create list of generic object at runtime

Tags: c#, generics

I have object of some type known at runtime and I read and deserialize this object from database. It works. Now I would like to add it to some list:

```
private static List<T> generateList<T>()
{
    List<T> lst = new List<T>();
    return lst;
}

private void readObjects(System.Type objType)
{
    var methodInfo = typeof(My.Serializator).GetMethod("DeserializeDb");
    var genericMethod = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(objType1);
    List<curType> currentList= generateList<curType>();
    // ...read stream from database and convert it to object
    while (_rs.Read())
    {
        var _objItem = genericMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { _streamedData });
        currentList.Add(_objItem);
    }
}
```

It won't work. The error is:

> curType is a variable but is used like a type.

If I change list to:

```
 List<object> currentList = new List<object>();
```

it will work. But can i do this with generics(T) instead of object type?

Comment: No, you can´t expect your compiler to infer a type that you provide only at runtime. This whateever you´re doing using reflection or whatever will *allways* just return `object`. You have to know at compile-type what exact type it actually is.

Comment: have you tried to change your method to readObjects<T>() ? and tweak your method to get the type based on T...

Comment: How do you call `ReadObjects`? And what are you doing with `currentList` afterwards?

Comment: We cannot see if `curType` is a type or a variable or something else because you do not show it. If `curType` is an expression of type `System.Type`, that is a variable, not a "type".

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Based on the error the OP gets we´re pretty sure that `curType` is just a variable holding a runtime-type.

Comment: You are using `curType` but it is not declared anywhere. Did you mean `objType`? If so, please edit the question.

Comment: Notwithstanding the actual answer (which is to use Reflection), the method `generateList<T>()` as it is shown and used here is totally unneeded. Just use `new List<T>()` in such situations.

Comment: Why don't you make `readObjects` generic? Since it's some kind of deserialization, presumably it's caller should know the proper type at compile-time? Why do you actually *want* to use runtime reflection?

Comment: we wont be able to help unless you show more details, like what is curType, _rs, objType1 and _streamedData

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easly create type of list you want via `Activator`, then cast to `IList` and use it:

```
private IList readObjects(System.Type objType)
{
    var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(curType);
    var list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);

    // ...

    while (_rs.Read())
    {
        // ...
        list.Add(_objItem);
    }
}
```

`list` will be instance of `List<YorActualType>`.

*Update*

When you declaring your method with generic arguments, it assumes you provide type info during compile time. Otherwise you need to use reflection.

Since you providing type info in run time (`curType` can hold any type info), compiler does not know what exactly type will be used, and you cannot declare your method to return something concrete. Only abstractions allowed.

Let's me show it on slightly insane but demonstrative example:

```
var types = new [] { typeof(int), typeof(string) };
var rand = new Random();
var list = readObjects(types[rand.Next(0,2)];
```

Until the very last moment even you will not know what exactly type of list will be created. Compiler does not know too. Compiler will never know what exactly type should be used if you not provide him with you types. When you use `Type` it only tells compiler that some regular parameter with type `Type` will be passed into the method in run time. There is no data to infer a type during compile time. That data can be passed only via [generic type parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2.aspx).

So, there is several ways you can follow:

1. Provide exact types you need at compile time

   ```
   private List<T> readObjects<T>()
   {
       var objType = typeof(T);
       var list = new List<T>();
       // rest of code....
   }
   ```
2. Use reflection and base types

   ```
   private IList readObjects(Type objType)
   {
       // rest of code with Activator and so on
   }
   ```

   And later usage depends on your needs.
   If you know what type you going to use, simply convert:

   ```
   var list = (IList<MyType>)readObjects(typeof(myType));
   ```

   But I guess in that case better use way #1 with generic argument.

   Otherwise you going to use reflection. Or some base classes, interfaces and so on. It depends on what exactly task you going to solve.

P.S. You can read more about [generic types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: However this won´t prevent someone to put an instance of any different type into that list, at least not during compile-time - which is impossible. What you get instead is an `ArgumentException` indicating that the provided type cannot be added to the generic list.

Comment: @HimBromBeere sure, there will no compile-time checks. But during run time this will throw an exception. Also his mothod to get data is generic so unlikely that error will be thrown. I believe that method returns value of generic argument type.

Comment: Thank you. It is what I wanted. And if I have method which returns this list, how should I declare it and call it?
private List<T> readObjects(System.Type objType)

Comment: Ok, I have now: "private IList readObjects(Type objType)" and "var dbData = readData(myType);" since i don't know the type(I get type at runtime from database inside readObjects method).It works, at the end i have IList of objects of the right type. Just this more: i have method: "public static void WriteToXmlFile<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite, bool append = false) where T : new()" and i have iList: "var dbData = readData(myType);" How can I call the method writeToXmlFile, something like:"WriteToXmlFile<typeof(dbData)>("C:\salesmen.txt", dbData);"

Comment: @Simon You can call `WriteToXmlFile` the same way you call `DeserializeDb`. However if it your code you'd better remove generics in that cases. Why you need them when this code should be able to serialize anything? Using `object` instead of `T` looks more reasonable. Also there is suspicious `new()` constraint on generic argument on serialization method. Does this method create instances of `T`? Why? It is expected to serialize existing instance.

Comment: Thanks, I can use object instead of generics.